# OpenOffice.org API or LibreOffice API?

Tags: openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno, odf

Which API should I use? Which one is more promising? My main goal is to generate ODF documents. It's important for me to support ODF 1.2. And I want to use C++ and CLI bingings.

Comment: Most of the development effort seems to be behind LO, so in terms of future planning that is probably the way forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use OpenOffice API a lot in an application of me. I made some tests with LibreOffice too and there **are** some (as far as i see undocumented and unwanted!) differences allready! (OO 3.2 against LO 3.4 and 3.5) Not much but here and there teh LO-Api behaves different from the OO-Api even in the same functionality. This is not important if you only deal with one of them, but it is important when you have to be sure that your App runs with OO and LO.

Comment: can you point some of the differences out? I work for 3 years with the UNO-API now, and I am not aware of any changes or different behaviour in LO compared to OO.

Answer (score 3):

There is nearly no difference between the two APIs ATM. At least before Libreoffice 4.0 ( which is only in planning with no specific date ) there might be some long necessary API clean-ups. All in all they should be even c++ binary compatible.

Right now you should be able to use the same extensions/code to access both Libreoffice and Openoffice. You should only be careful with all interfaces marked as LibO 3.4 or 3.5 from http://api.libreoffice.org/